# String To dictionary Conversion always having Nil values

Tags: ios, string, dictionary, swift3

It's strange issue here. I am trying to convert String into Dictionary in Swift 3.0 but dictionary always having nil values. I Don't know why

Here is my code for String to Dictionary Conversion.

```
 var receivedMessage = [String: String]()
 var MessageReceived:String!

 do
 {
     let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: MessageReceived:String, options: .prettyPrinted)       
     let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
     if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String:String]
     {                    
          print("MessageReceived",dictFromJSON)
     }
 }
 catch
 {
     print(error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

And My String that is here **receivedMessage** is like this.

> {"_id":15, "isMine":true, "isReaded":false, "msgId":"1485956711767",
>   "msgText":"okkk", "myId":"218", "myJId":"1101784499938497_218_147300",
>   "senderName":"Burea", "time":"7:15PM", "timeStamp":1485956711768,
>   "userId":"203", "userJId":"1234840263264009_203_496216" }

and the output that I get as a dictionary is:
**received message [:]**

Well Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: `receivedMessage` is already `Dictionary` not `String`.

Comment: Also `receivedMessage` is empty as per your code

Comment: it's JSON String not Dictionary @Nirav

Comment: Yes receivedMessage Dictionary is Empty when i try to convert @in

Comment: json should be converted like this.. as? [String: AnyObject]

Comment: The JSON contains also integers. It could not be `[String:String]`. And why do you convert dictionary to JSON and right back??

Comment: @MadBurea You have declare `receivedMessage` as `[String: String]` so it is `Dictionary` not string

Comment: No no it's String as i Written Wrong Variable there .. isssue is still remaining

Comment: did you try [String: Any]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get `Data` from string using `data(using:)` method of String.

```
if let jsonData = messageReceived.data(using: .utf8) { 
    let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)
    if let dic = decoded as? [String:Any] { //Instead of [String:String] 
         print(dic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this, e.g.

```
//your json string 
let receivedMessage = "{\"_id\":15, \"isMine\":true, \"isReaded\":false, \"msgId\":\"1485956711767\", \"msgText\":\"okkk\", \"myId\":\"218\", \"myJId\":\"1101784499938497_218_147300\", \"senderName\":\"Burea\", \"time\":\"7:15PM\", \"timeStamp\":1485956711768, \"userId\":\"203\", \"userJId\":\"1234840263264009_203_496216\"}"
//convert that json string into data
let jsonData = receivedMessage.data(using: .utf8)
do {
  //decode the json
  let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!)
  // use [String: Any] instead of [String: String] since your some values are int 
  if let dictFromJSON = decoded as? [String: Any] {
    print("MessageReceived", dictFromJSON)
  }
} catch {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

---

Console o/p

> MessageReceived ["myId": 218, "senderName": Burea, "myJId": 1101784499938497_218_147300, "_id": 15, "isReaded": 0, "userJId": 1234840263264009_203_496216, "userId": 203, "isMine": 1, "msgId": 1485956711767, "msgText": okkk, "timeStamp": 1485956711768, "time": 7:15PM]